# Youtube video does not play after clearing the cache

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I have added a Youtube video inside the CKEditor to load the video in Colorbox, in a content type from CKEditor plugin (plugin is extact data from view). It works fine after creating content.

After clearing cache the URL does not work. It show only http:// in Colorbox. Please give me some suggestions.

The sample URL is /?q=vef/load/fe380247ab1fef057fca83a1df37326c&width=640px&height=363, inside CKEditor.

Comment: You are not using Media?

Comment: No i am not using media, i am using video_embed_field.But i fix the bug by reconstructing the urls as like embed video and adding the parameter link this "?fs=1&amp;width=640&amp;height=480&amp;hl=en_US1&amp;iframe=true&amp;rel=0".

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enter url in the embed_video_field. Following is the sample url
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWKsjaEtKs

You can set other parameters like height, width using embed video field configuration.